# Question regarding $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ representation theory.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I´m working myself right now through this [article](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf) and have a question regarding the proof of Proposition 6.4, case II) on page 345-346. I try to give a short outline of the situation:

---

We have $G \subset SL(V)$ a connected algebraic group, acting irreducible on a complex vectorspace $V$ and a reflection $r \in GL(V)$ which normalizes $G$ and has special eigenvalue $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$. In the proof we consider the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, which is semisimple and also acts irreducible on $V$. Now in said case II) we have, that $r-Id \in \mathfrak{g}$ is a nilpotent element. By application of the [Jacobson-Morozov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson%E2%80%93Morozov_theorem), said nilpotent element is contained in a subalgebra $\mathfrak{s} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ with $\mathfrak{s} \simeq \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Then the author states

**Since the dimension of $ker(r-Id)=n-1$ we deduce by $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representation theory, that $\mathbb{C}^n \simeq \mathbb{C}^2 \oplus \mathbb{C}^{n-2}$ as an $\mathfrak{s}$ module.**

And I was wondering, to what exactly he is refering to with $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representation theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the last few days you have asked a huge number of questions about this paper you are reading. I think you might gain more by spending a bit more time working on it yourself before asking for help.

In this case all they are saying is that if the kernel of $r-\mathrm{Id}$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional the only possible $n$-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ rep with that property is the sum of a $(n-2)$-dimensional trivial rep $\mathbb{C}^{n-2}$ and the $2$-dimensional standard rep $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Then $r-\mathrm{Id}$ is $0$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n-2}$ and has $1$-dimensional kernel on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

This is just from basic properties of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ reps. The key observation is that any $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ irrep has a $1$-dimensional kernel (for any of its nilpotent elements in fact but perhaps more simply for $e$ and $f$ in the usual basis $e,f,h \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$).

Comment: But wouldn't that kinda be a contrafiction? If i aplly the J.-M. Thrm. onto the nilpotent element $e=r-Id$ and extent to a $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ triple $\{e,f,h\}$, then how can the kernel of $e$ be one dimensional since i already have, that it is of dimension $n-1$? Or do you mean te kernel of $\rho(e)$ is one dimensional, where $\rho$ is said representation?

Comment: The kernel of $\rho(e)$ is $1$-dimensional for any **irreducible** representation $\rho$. Thus you can intuit possibilities for the decomposition of a given representation into irreducibles if you know the dimension of the kernel of the whole (non-irreducible) representation. In this case the additional information of the dimension of $V$ fixes exactly one possibility

Comment: Thank you very much. And i know that my questions are annoying, but i really appreciate the help.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I am not annoyed by the questions. I just think it is good to spend some time stuck on problems. You learn more by figuring it out on your own or at least bashing your head against it for a time. Of course, having said that, there will always be ones you can't solve by yourself.